# Update-alternatives isn't changing python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, version

I tried following the instructions here: [Cloudbytes instruction for changing version of python 3](https://cloudbytes.dev/snippets/upgrade-python-to-latest-version-on-ubuntu-linux) changing the version for python and python3.

Everything seemed ok I ended up with:

```
Selection Path                 Priority       Status
---------------------------------------------------
0         /usr/bin/python3.10        3        auto mode
1         /usr/bin/python3.10        3        manual mode
2         /anaconda3/bin/python3.9   2        manual mode
3         /usr/bin/python3.8         1        manual mode
```

But when I run : `python --version` I get

```
Python 3.9.12
```

Is there another way my python version is getting set? I'm guessing it has something to do with anaconda but I'm not sure how to change that.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of multiple links on python3.9 in your system and alternatives is overwritten.
Try to print the version of the python that you currently using.

```
which python
```

or

```
which python3.9
```

Replace python3.9 link.

Comment: How to you replace python link?